# Server not getting POST method body from XmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest

I have a client side JavaScript code, sending commands to a server using the `XmlHttpRequest()` POST method. The client side code is:

```
var serverURL = "http://myserver.com:3000"

function sendCommand(command, argsForCommand) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = recvResponse;
    xhr.open("POST", (serverURL + "/" + command), true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(argsForCommand);
}
```

The server expects the POST message in the form:

---

POST  HTTP/1.1

....HTTP headers....

....HTTP headers....

argsForCommand

---

i.e. the command that the server must execute is part of the POST line and the arguments (which may be short or long) are in the body of the message.

The server is one that I have written myself and have tested with another client, so I know the server side is working. The server listens on a non-standard port (3000 in this example) for connections from clients.

My problem is that after my code calls the `sendCommand()` function, I get the POST message at the server only until the HTTP headers; I do not get the arguments (the POST message body). If I refresh the client page in which the code executes, the arguments appear at the server. Any help on what I could be missing is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Everything appears to be correct (except it won't work in some versions of IE), have you console logged argsForCommand to make sure they contain valid data?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the value(s) in the argsForCommand and they appear correct. And, in fact, they are received at the server when I do a refresh/reload on the browser. I suspect that when the refresh/reload is done, maybe some tcp flush is happening which is sending it out. Also, I am using Google-Chrome when testing this. I have not checked it with IE.

Comment: What does the request look like in the network inspector?

Comment: I am not using any network inspector. At the server, I am able to see the following message received (I print it out at the server as and when the server receives anything).

Comment: I mean on chrome, you can open up the dev tools (right click - inspect element is easiest way), the view the network requests.

Comment: Sorry, the previous edit went out before I completed it. Here's what I see at the server
POST /reportNodeConnectionsMap HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 30
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
Origin: null
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Comment: Is the Form Data present? It should be right below the request headers.

Comment: Thank you so much. I saw that the client's XmlHttpRequest was indeed being sent out. At the server, I was expecting a newline character to process the last line. But I had not added the newline at the end of the request from the client. Stupid mistake on my part. Your pointer helped me to debug it and resolve it now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad I could be of help!